# Inventor iLogic, save all .idw sheets to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, autodesk-inventor

I am creating an iLogic External Rule in Inventor 2016 to save the .idw file I'm working on to a PDF. So far the code is beautifully short and simple and works like a charm for single-sheet files. I have a few lines that define the directory location (PDFPath) which culminates into this final line:

```
ThisDoc.Document.SaveAs(PDFPath & "\" & ThisDoc.FileName(False) & ".pdf" , True)
```

The problem is that this will only save the active sheet. When running this rule I need it to save all sheets, however many there may be.

Answer (score 0):

This had the code I needed:

[From The Trenches with Autodesk Inventor: iLogic To Save PDF Files To a New Subfolder](http://inventortrenches.blogspot.com/2011/07/ilogic-to-save-pdf-files-to-new.html)

Answer (score 0):

That link works - as I used that code for part of my PDF creation, but there is a flaw with it.

If your views are not up to date - you will get a PDF with geometry missing.  like the line weight has been reduced to zero.

once you update the views, run the PDf again, it generates normally.

this does not so this when you use the manual method.

I'm working on finding code to add to mine, that will update views prior to pdf creation as I suspect the manual method does that, but doing it via illogic does not.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to insert this code above the export part:

```
update InventorVb.DocumentUpdate()
```